# images coming from an sql array not showing up

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm trying to make the top 5 images from my sql table, NEWS, appear in a row. When I try this, a row of empty image boxes appear. The collumn `image` says the directory of the image. I double checked to make sure it was the exact directory.

```
<?php 
   $leaders=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT `image` FROM news ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 5"));
   for ($i=1; $i<=5; $i++)
      {
?>
<img src="<?php echo($leaders[$i])?>" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;"></img>
<?php
   }
?>
```

Anybody know why the images aren't showing up?
ALSO, I tested it on the sql command line client. the

```
SELECT `image` FROM news ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 5
```

does show the image url. It should be working.

Comment: **Heads up!** Future versions of PHP are *deprecating and removing* the `mysql_` family of functions. Now would be a great time to [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysql_fetch_array` (which is deprecated) returns 1 single row, not the whole resultset. You need it to fetch another row. Something like this would work:

```
 <?php 
  $leaders=mysql_query("SELECT `image` FROM news ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 5");
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($leaders)){
   ?>
     <img src="<?php echo($leaders['image'])?>" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;"></img>
  <?php
  }
```

But seriously, look to `PDO` & start converting.

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand how `mysql_fetch_array` works. It gets one row from the result set (your first image) so you would have to loop through all results to get all images.

But you should do that in PDO / mysqli as the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.